# Can't quit XAMPP normally

Tags: xampp

I use the win10 system. My xampp panel is v3.2.4. The xampp can run  mysql and apache normally. But when I want to quit, the program will report an error, then no response. Need help, please. How can I fix this?

Add：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC002.png), the Chinese words in this picture means access denied.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpNyS.png)
When I click quit bottom in xampp, it will show me these two hints.

This is my xampp-control.ini [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0yxL.png)

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to the people who distribute that software, though they're going to need to walk you through how to get some detailed technical information about the problem. One thing's for sure -- this is not a question about programming.

Comment: Please update your Question with the steps you are taking to 'quit' so we have an idea of your process.

Answer (score 10):

Are you running the program as an administrator?

Make sure you have installed XAMPP outside of the Program Files folder, the default should warn you about that and suggest installing in C:\xampp anyway.

You may also need to go to the C:\xampp directory and change the settings for xampp-control.exe too. Right click on it, go to Properties > Compatibility and then check the "Run this program as an administrator".

Answer (score 9):

Find file **xampp-control.ini** into folder XAMPP, **changes permisssion for everyone with FULL CONTROL**

Comment: This is the one and only solution that worked for me. This should be marked as the answer. However, I am unaware of the adverse effects of changing the default permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Open file location of Xampp Control Panel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqhaP.png

Right click on XAMPP Control Panel -> Properties -> Advanced. Then tick to "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 1):

you have to run as administrator

if you don't want to click all the time run as administrator
you should set it to run as administrator

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8Z2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

- Find file xampp-control.ini into folder XAMPP
- Delete it
- Start xampp control panel

This will create a new xampp-control.ini with the correct rights.