# XAMPP Quit problem, xampp is not Quiting, showing below error instead

Tags: xampp

this is first error:

[image]

this is second error:

[image]

xampp giving me 2 errors when i quiting xampp, i wanna close xampp, help me!

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013824/7284577 helped me
check it please and upvote if helped to you

Answer (score 0):

Use task manager to kill program and the next time you run it ,run it as administrator if using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings to run in compatibility mode for windows 8, this can be done by right clicking on xampp-control which is located in the xampp installation folder and selecting properties from the contextual menu then select the Compatibility tab and modify to run this program in compatibility for Windows 8.

**Screenshot**

[image]